# SQS DeleteMessage blocks and does not return a response

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm processing an sqs message in a lambda function and once its processed successfully I try and delete it. This is where the issue comes in. It seems like the call to `deleteMessage` just does not complete. The lambda function times out after 100 seconds before `deleteMessage` returns.

Below is the code sample used to try and delete the message. 
I pass the queueUrl along with the message when I send it as a hack in the interim (dealing with queue url's, arns and names is messy and inconsistant at the moment).

I have validated that the queueUrl and ReceiptHandle are correct.

```
async deleteSQSMessage(record: SQSRecord) {
    try {

        let queueUrl: any = record.messageAttributes['queueUrl']

        console.log(`Deleting message from queue: ${JSON.stringify(queueUrl)}`)

        if(queueUrl) {
            console.log(`Deleting queue message: ${record.body}`)
            let sqs = new SQS()
            let deleteParams = { QueueUrl: queueUrl.stringValue, ReceiptHandle: record.receiptHandle }
            // THIS IS THE LAST STATEMENT PRINTED IN THE LOGS (AFTER 100 SECS THE LAMBDA FUNCTION TIMES OUT
            console.log(`Delete params: ${JSON.stringify(deleteParams)}`)
            let result = await sqs.deleteMessage(deleteParams).promise()
            console.log(`Delete result: ${result}`)
        } else {
            console.error(`Invalid event record, no queueUrl attribute, cant delete message off of queue. ${record}`)
        }

    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err))
    }
}
```

I have added this VPC endpoint to enable access to sqs:

```
SQSVPCEndpoint:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpoint
    Properties:
      ServiceName: !Sub 'com.amazonaws.${AWS::Region}.sqs'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      VpcEndpointType: Interface
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB
        - !Ref SubnetC
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref VPCSecurityGroup
```

Security group referenced above:

```
VPCSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: 'Open security group for subnet IPS'
      VpcId: !Ref VPC

  VPCSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref VPCSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 0
      ToPort: 65535
      SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref VPCSecurityGroup

  VPCSecurityGroupEgress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupEgress
    Properties:
      GroupId: !Ref VPCSecurityGroup
      IpProtocol: tcp
      FromPort: 0
      ToPort: 65535
      DestinationSecurityGroupId: !Ref VPCSecurityGroup
```

I have given the lambda full access to sqs:
[image: Full access]

And on the queue itself I have allowed anyone to perform any action:
[image]

Anyone have any Ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: Any time a Lambda function is timing out like this, the first thing to do is to increase the lambda timeout so that you can give the *real* exception sufficient time to fire.  It certainly appears to be a connectivity issue, but it's all speculation until you confirm that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had a few missing attributes on my VPC and the EndPoint...

I added these to the VPC

```
EnableDnsSupport: true
EnableDnsHostnames: true
```

And added this to the endpoint

```
PrivateDnsEnabled: true
```

And then the lambda function was finally able to communicate with SQS